# Returning 2 subclassed objects back to delete, should it be 2 seperate methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns

I have 2 subclassed `MKAnnotation' objects. I need to return each type at some point in my class.

Should I have:

```
-(void)returnAnnotation:(MKAnnotation *)myAnnotation;
```

and let the method check object class and go from there?

```
-(void)returnAnnotation:(MKAnnotation *)myAnnotation {
    if ([myAnnotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotationA Class]]) {
        // do stuff
    } else if ([myAnnotation isKindOfClass:[MyAnnotationB Class]]) {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

Or

```
-(void)returnAnnotationA:(MyANnotationA *)myAnnotationA;

-(void)returnAnnotationA:(MyAnnotationB *)myAnnotationB;
```

The former helps reduce methods and makes it easier to know which delegate method to call.

But the latter is more concise and may be easier to understand whats happening.

Or is this basically 6 one way half a dozen the other?

Or is it Readability vs Writeablity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case it doesn't seem to make a difference, but I would recommend using:

```
-(void)returnAnnotationA:(MyANnotationA *)myAnnotationA;
-(void)returnAnnotationA:(MyAnnotationB *)myAnnotationB;
```

To ensure that only a valid MKAnnotation subclass is passed in. You shouldn't allow a MKAnnotation object or any other future subclasses to be passed in if the method does not explicitly handle them properly.

Comment: Yep, I agree. After some thought, I realized the simple `-(void)returnAnnotation:(MKAnnotation *)myAnnotation` could lead to somebody thinking they could pass in a `MKAnnotationC` and assume the delegate would know how to handle it.